# ionic installation issue windows

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

Hello im trying to install ionic on my windows computer, i already installed `nodejs` and `cordova` but i m having this problem when i use the command `npm install -g ionic`

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g ionic
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Windows\system32\-g
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\nodejs\\node.exe"       
"C:\\Users\\Alejandro\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v4.2.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.1
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\-g
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\system32\-g'

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open   'C:\Windows\system32\-g'

npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Try at different directories other than system dir, `Windows\system32` is kinda hell to do things.

Comment: i think you have problem with your environment setup. You can check the complete guide to ionic installation to building of android project @ http://ionicsupport.blogspot.com/2015/12/beginners-guide-for-installation-of.html?showComment=1451365384397#c6175594702417901582  . See if it helps you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic installing error in windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569929/ionic-installing-error-in-windows-7)