# ionic installing error in windows 7

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I followed the instruction from [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) to install ionic on windows7,but I got the error.

Current installed other utility versions are :

```
nodejs version 4.3.1

npm version 2.14.12

cordova version 6.0.0
```

When I trying to install ionic I get the following result

```
C:\Users\pranav>npm install -g ionic

npm WARN deprecated gulp-minify-css@0.3.13: Please use gulp-cssnano instead.

npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.

npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm

npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. > spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall C:\Users\pranav\node_modules\ew\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\cross-spawn\node_modules\spawn-sync > node postinstall /

node-sass@3.4.2 install C:\Users\pranav\node_modules\ew\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass

node scripts/install.js Binary downloaded and installed at C:\Users\pranav\node_modules\ew\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-46\binding.node > node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall C:\Users\pranav\node_modules\ew\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass > node scripts/build.js 
C:\Users\pranav\node_modules\ew\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-46\binding.node exists. testing binary. Binary is fine; exiting. ew@1.1.1 C:\Users\pranav\node_modules\ew 
├── gulp-rename@1.2.2 
├── gulp-concat@2.6.0 (concat-with-sourcemaps@1.0.4, through2@0.6.5, gulp-util@3.0.7) 
├── gulp-minify-css@0.3.13 (memory-cache@0.0.5, vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.1.4, bufferstreams@0.0.2, through2@0.6.5, clean-css@3.0.10, gulp-util@3.0.7) 
├── gulp@3.9.1 (interpret@1.0.0, pretty-hrtime@1.0.2, deprecated@0.0.1, archy@1.0.0, minimist@1.2.0, semver@4.3.6, tildify@1.1.2, v8flags@2.0.11, chalk@1.1.1, orchestrator@0.3.7, liftoff@2.2.0, vinyl-fs@0.3.14, gulp-util@3.0.7) 
└── gulp-sass@2.2.0 (object-assign@4.0.1, vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.2.1, through2@2.0.1, gulp-util@3.0.7, node-sass@3.4.2)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you install cordova globally

Comment: npm install -g cordova

Comment: ya i can install it there is no problem

Comment: can you install the git

Comment: i have git in my pc already

Comment: please check your git version

Comment: git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104234/discussion-between-santosh-shinde-and-pranavadurai).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to download and install [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win).

To install Cordova, make sure you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed, then run

```
 npm install -g cordova
```

Windows users developing for Android: You'll want to make sure you have the following installed and set up.

NOTE: Whenever you make changes to the PATH, or any other environment variable, you'll need to restart or open a new tab in your shell program for the PATH change to take effect.

**Java JDK**

Install the most recent Java JDK (NOT just the JRE).

Next, create an environment variable for JAVA_HOME pointing to the root folder where the Java JDK was installed. So, if you installed the JDK into C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7, set JAVA_HOME to be this path. After that, add the JDK's bin directory to the PATH variable as well. Following the previous assumption, this should be either %JAVA_HOME%\bin or the full path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7\bin

**Apache Ant**

To install Ant, download a zip from here, extract it, move the first folder in the zip to a safe place, and update your PATH to include the bin folder in that folder. For example, if you moved the Ant folder to c:/, you'd want to add this to your PATH: C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin.

**Android SDK**

Installing the Android SDK is also necessary. The Android SDK provides you the API libraries and developer tools necessary to build, test, and debug apps for Android.

Cordova requires the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to be set. This should point to the [ANDROID_SDK_DIR]\android-sdk directory (for example c:\android\android-sdk).

Next, update your PATH to include the tools/ and platform-tools/ folder in that folder. So, using ANDROID_HOME, you would add both %ANDROID_HOME%\tools and %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools.

**Install Ionic**

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Hope this will help you !