# Ionic platform add android error: Failed to install cordova-plugin-console

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have all set up .
I have installed android sdk api 24 and all the necessary tools. I have also tried reinstalling ionic and cordova but it does not work.

This is the error log:

```
D:\Coursera\Course 4\myapp1\public>ionic platform add android
Adding android project...


Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:


        Path: platforms\android

        Package: com.ionicframework.myapp1409522


        Name: myapp1
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-24

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0


Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for android


Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-console':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit
code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Sahib\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:213:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)


Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422961/cordova-cannot-add-android-failed-with-exit-code-enoent

Comment: I have added C:\Windows\System32 in the PATH. Still getting this error

Comment: Have you set the  JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME environment variables ?

Comment: And add android to path?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are not adding environment variable.

Please go through  following steps :

Windows users developing for Android: You'll want to make sure you have the following installed and set up.

NOTE: Whenever you make changes to the PATH, or any other environment variable, you'll need to restart or open a new tab in your shell program for the PATH change to take effect.

**Java JDK**

Install the most recent Java JDK (NOT just the JRE).

Next, create an environment variable for `JAVA_HOME` pointing to the root folder where the Java JDK was installed. So, if you installed the JDK into `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7`, set `JAVA_HOME` to be this path. After that, add the JDK's bin directory to the PATH variable as well. Following the previous assumption, this should be either `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` or the full path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7\bin`

**Apache Ant**

To install Ant, download a zip from here, extract it, move the first folder in the zip to a safe place, and update your PATH to include the bin folder in that folder. For example, if you moved the Ant folder to `c:/`, you'd want to add this to your PATH: `C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin`.

**Android SDK**

Installing the Android SDK is also necessary. The Android SDK provides you the API libraries and developer tools necessary to build, test, and debug apps for Android.

Cordova requires the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to be set. This should point to the `[ANDROID_SDK_DIR]\android-sdk` directory (for example c:\android\android-sdk).

Next, update your PATH to include the tools/ and platform-tools/ folder in that folder. So, using `ANDROID_HOME`, you would add both `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools` and `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`.

For more please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569929/ionic-installing-error-in-windows-7) and [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/hybrid-mobile-apps-with-ionic-framework.html).

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: Sahib Navlani using Cordova 6.0 and from Cordova 4.0 - it does not use ANT. Uses Gradle instead. Please check @ https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was to add the Environmentvariable:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m
```

You may vary the 512m by your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you need to add "C:\Windows\System32" to your path variable.